# What is the equivalent degrees of one "turn"

Tags: installation, bolts

Often in install or specification manuals you will see something like:

> Tighten X **turns** past finger tight

[Example](http://www.powers.com/pdfs/mechanical/06914.pdf)
[image: install instruction of powers sleeve anchor]

This has always bothered me as it seems ambiguous.  I've always taken this to mean a "turn of the hand".  Depending on flexibility, seems like this would be a little less than 180 degrees?

However, it could also easily be interpreted as a full rotation (360 degrees)....

I'm honestly surprised that the lawyers allow this in technical specs like the example above (why not just give torque?).

Comment: good follow up question:  `What is the torque of "hand-tight"?`

Comment: A: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/finger_tight

Comment: Well those instructions are rather vague...

Comment: surprisingly so for something that could potentially be supporting 1000s of lb.  In the chart above they have `Max Bolt Torque, Tmax (ft-lbs)`... however, it's MAX, so I'm not sure if that's the ideal installation torque or the point of failure

Comment: I always read instructions like that then allow an adjustment for the materials I am working with...

Comment: Any competent fastener will have a rating based on lab tests. It will also be listed, *and not listed*, for certain loads.  Honestly this family of fastener is fairly hokey and is for light weight work.  If someone were attaching a ladder to a wall, they'd be using something like epoxy, but that is not consumer-marketable because there are too many ways to screw it up.

Comment: @Harper this is the go-to fastener for putting permanent rock climbing protection ("bolts") into natural rock walls.  Loads are light (single human falling on dynamic rope), but failure would be catastrophic...

Comment: Has the manufacturer certified it for climbing/life safety use, or is this "go-to" status news to them?

Comment: @Harper of course not!  No company would ever "certify" a fastener for climbing due to the inherent danger of rock climbing and variables that comes with placing an anchor in natural/variable material.  Hilti once had a webpage that promoted the use of their hammer drills for rockclimbers, but that was quickly taken down (I'm sure once their lawyers got wind).

They are the goto because they have proven to have the best trade off of holding power vs. ease of placement/replacement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A turn is 360 degrees.

You are expected to put a mark on the thing you are turning, so you can observe its rotation.

They have no way of knowing which kind of wrench you are using, what your wrenching style is, or what amount of swing angle local clearances will afford you.

"Hand/finger tight" is the point at which all free lash/slop has been removed, further turning actually loads the fastener, and torque becomes measurable.

In a fastener in tension, how much strain a "turn" amounts to depends an awful lot on the length of the fastener subject to tension. Getting from "strain" to "torque" then involves a lot of other stuff.

In the case of the anchor in your link, it has little to do with tension.  It is intentionally deforming the anchor to make it engage the hole you just drilled.

Comment: well... In that case I've been doing this correctly for a long time (luckily not for this particular use case).  Wish they had just said 1080-1440 degrees...

Comment: When I tighten something hand tight, my friends have to find a spanner to get it undone... Mind you, serious tech to "put a mark on the thing you are turning" ...

Comment: also, I assume then that the `Max Bolt Torque, Tmax (ft-lbs)` in the above spec, would indicate the rated torque of the bolt (not to be exceeded) and has nothing to do with installation torque (except that you should not exceed it when installing)

Comment: @NSjonas, you can't expect the average person to have any idea what 1440 degrees is or even how to figure that out.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Really...because I passed the 3rd grade.

Comment: @LeeSam, yea, after high school I worked at Home Depot for a while and it's surprising how much people don't know.  I'm sure any mechanic can tell you the same.

Comment: I think ideally it would say both: `3 turns (1080 degrees) past finger tight`.

The problem is that "turn" is both a verb and a "measurement".  

EG you "turn" a key to unlock a door, but that often doesn't require a completed a full 360 degrees of movement.

Answer (score 1):

Finger tight will engage the wedge against the sleeve. You need 3-4 full 360 degree turns to lift the wedge 3-4 full threads and apply the intended lateral force against the sides of the drilled hole.

Many plumbing fittings with rubber gaskets or cone washers will say something like "1/4 turn past finger tight". It means the same thing.